# Книги Win32 API (?)

Tags: winapi, книги, c++

Посоветуйте с какой книги лучше начать изучать Win32 API на С++:

1) Win32 API. Эффективная разработка приложений (Юрий Щупак)
2) Win32 API. Разработка приложений для Windows (Юрий Щупак)
3) Технология программирования на C++. Win32 API-приложения (Н. А. Литвиненко)

Прошу отвечать, пожалуйста, тех, кто читал данные книги!

Comment: Рихтер, конечно же старый друг Рихтер !

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте! Книги только обогащают Ваш багаж знаний, программировать нужно не по книге, а исходя из своих актуальных умений в этой области. Предлагаю не начинать с книги, а поставить вопрос - что я хочу запрограммировать. После этого можно обогащать базу знаний. Например, книги 1, 2, 3 могут быть изучены согласно одного вопроса, допустим "потоки". Сделайте микс "у себя в голове",  на тему "потоки". Теперь Вы это умеете, т.к  ваше умение получено при прочтении не одной книги, а более. Система это не только компьютерный термин. Система знаний, умений, навыков... читайте как можно больше, и разную литературу: документацию, книги ...
Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

По личному опыту скажу так, сам начал читать что-то только тогда, когда что-то конкретное не получалось. Не вижу особого смысла вычитывать книги, если не понятно к чему применять полученные знания. WinAPI довольно объёмная тема и вообще сложно сказать есть ли смысл читать что-то конкретное по этой теме, тем более, что сугубо на WinAPI стоит писать что-то совсем специфическое.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше книги по программированию Windows, чем [книга Петцольда](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/157231995X), на мой взгляд, просто нет. Не смотрите, что она старая - Win32 API тоже не молод. Разумеется, весь Win32 API оп ней не выучишь, но начать вполне можно. Потом, уже будете познавать различные области Win32 API по мере надобности.